# Handle all Events for an aggregate

Tags: c#, event-sourcing

Please see my first Persistent Subscription below:

```
 namespace PersistentSubscription
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            private static void Main()
            {
                var subscription = new PersistentSubscriptionClient();
                subscription.Start();
            }
        }

        public class PersistentSubscriptionClient
        {
            private IEventStoreConnection _conn;
            private const string STREAM = "$ce-customer";
            private const string GROUP = "a_test_group";
            private const int DEFAULTPORT = 1113;
            private static readonly UserCredentials User = new UserCredentials("admin", "changeit");
            private EventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase _subscription;

            public void Start()
            {
                var settings = ConnectionSettings.Create(); 

                using (_conn = EventStoreConnection.Create(settings, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, DEFAULTPORT)))
                {
                    _conn.ConnectAsync().Wait();

                    CreateSubscription(); 
                    ConnectToSubscription();

                    Console.WriteLine("waiting for events. press enter to exit");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            private void ConnectToSubscription()
            {
                var bufferSize = 10;
                var autoAck = true;

                Action<EventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase, ResolvedEvent> eventAppeared = EventAppeared; 
                _subscription = _conn.ConnectToPersistentSubscription(STREAM, GROUP, eventAppeared, SubscriptionDropped, User, bufferSize, autoAck);
            }

            private void SubscriptionDropped(EventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase eventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase,
                SubscriptionDropReason subscriptionDropReason, Exception ex)
            {
                ConnectToSubscription();
            }

            private static void EventAppeared(EventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase eventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase,
                ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(resolvedEvent.Event.Data);
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                try
                {
                    CustomerCreated customerCreated = (CustomerCreated)formatter.Deserialize(stream); 
                    Console.WriteLine(customerCreated);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var test = "test";
                }

            }

            private void CreateSubscription()
            {
                PersistentSubscriptionSettings settings = PersistentSubscriptionSettings.Create()
                    .DoNotResolveLinkTos()
                    .StartFromCurrent();

                try
                {
                    _conn.CreatePersistentSubscriptionAsync(STREAM, GROUP, settings, User).Wait();
                }
                catch (AggregateException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.InnerException.GetType() != typeof(InvalidOperationException)
                        && ex.InnerException?.Message != $"Subscription group {GROUP} on stream {STREAM} already exists")
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and my first client below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using EventStore.ClientAPI;

namespace WritingEvents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int DEFAULTPORT = 1113;
            var settings = ConnectionSettings.Create();
            using (var conn = EventStoreConnection.Create(settings, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, DEFAULTPORT)))
            {
                conn.ConnectAsync().Wait();
                CustomerCreated c1 = new CustomerCreated { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Maria" };
                EventData customerCreated1 = GetEventDataFor(c1);
                conn.AppendToStreamAsync("customer-100", ExpectedVersion.Any, customerCreated1).Wait();
            }
        }

        private static EventData GetEventDataFor(CustomerCreated customerCreated)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, customerCreated);
            byte[] customerCreatedEventByteArray = stream.ToArray();



            return new EventData(
                Guid.NewGuid(),
                "eventType",
                true,
                customerCreatedEventByteArray,
                null
                );
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CustomerCreated
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I run the server and then then the client.  I see an error when deserializing the CustomerCreated event on the server side.  The error is: "End of stream was encountered before parsing was completed".

If I change this line:

```
private const string STREAM = "$ce-customer";
```

to this:

```
private const string STREAM = "customer-100";
```

Then deserialization works correctly on the server side.

How do I handle all customer events - not just customer 100?

I have `--run-projections=all` when starting Event Store.  I have also enabled all projections:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use different streams for each event? Note that your `STREAM` string specifies the stream through which to transfer the events? Just use one string (i.e., a single stream name). If you need to transfer something like "customer-100" together with an event, then make it part of the event payload, i would suggest.

Comment: @elgonzo, there is one stream per customer and each customer will have many events.  At the moment I just have created events.  Do you know why I am unable to deserialize when subscribing to $ce-customer? I am new to event sourcing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use "$ce-customer" as some projection?

Comment: @elgonzo, yes I am.

Comment: Sorry, i deleted my last comment. I overlooked in your questions that you already have enabled projections. Hmm...

Comment: Since i never really did work with projections, i can only speculate. Perhaps (and just perhaps) ConnectToPersistentSubscription does not work with projections. An example from the documentation (https://eventstore.org/blog/20130707/catch-up-subscriptions-with-the-event-store/) uses the `SubscribeToStream` (or `SubscribeToStreamAsync` perhaps) method to read from a projection. Worth a try if not somebody else comes up with a better suggestion...

Comment: Poking around a little more in the doc and the EventStore issue tracker on GitHub, and it seems persistent subscriptions should work just fine with projection. Well, i am out of ideas. Sorry for not being more helpful :(

Comment: @elgonzo, I have posted my answer in case you are interested.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question helped me: [Using the Event Store Client API (.NET), how to I write to a stream and link one event to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906995/using-the-event-store-client-api-net-how-to-i-write-to-a-stream-and-link-one)

I simply had to change this:

```
PersistentSubscriptionSettings settings = PersistentSubscriptionSettings.Create()
                .DoNotResolveLinkTos() //Specifically this line
                .StartFromCurrent();
```

to this:

```
PersistentSubscriptionSettings settings = PersistentSubscriptionSettings.Create()
                .ResolveLinkTos() //Specifically this line
                .StartFromCurrent();
```

`DoNotResolveLinkTos` gets a **link** to the original event, whereas ResolveLinkTos gets the actual event itself.  Therefore I was trying to deserialize the link object, which was causing the exception.